# How to get a native srs and declared srs of layer using gsconfig?

Tags: geoserver, coordinate-system

How we can get native SRS and declared SRS of existed layer in GeoServer?

I'm getting up to layer name available in a particular store and work space.

The code as follows

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog  
cat=Catalog("http:// localhost:8080/geoserver/rest")  
myResource = cat.get_resources(store='storeName', workspace='workspaceName')  
layers = cat.get_layers(myResource)
for rss in myResorce:
print rss.name
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One further step missed for native box

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog  
cat=Catalog("http:// localhost:8080/geoserver/rest")  
myResource = cat.get_resources(store='storeName', workspace='workspaceName')  
layers = cat.get_layers(myResource)
for rss in myResorce:
print rss.name
print rss.native_bbox ## this is for native bounding box
print rss.projection ## for projection of a layer
```